# Qt, C++ - Editing an existing INI file from project doesn't work when I need to save it

Tags: c++, qt, ini, qwidget, qsettings

I'm using Qt. Included libraries are QWidget, QSettings, QDateTime.
I created a new INI file named **records.ini**, then I added it to my **resources.qrc** in prefix **stats**, so my path to this file is correct, I checked that.

I opened all tutorials and examples with QSettings and INI files and I did it all as it's shown below:

```
void SomeFinishingFunction()
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Game is over. Result: " + QString::number(points));

    QSettings *sett = new QSettings(":/stats/records.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    date = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

    sett->beginGroup("Player"); // + date.toString()
    sett->setValue("Record", 1000); // points
    sett->endGroup();

    sett->sync();

    Sleep(2500);
    this->close();
}
```

Also I tried to create **sett** as non-pointer variable:
`QSettings sett(":/stats/records.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);`
and did same things.

As I noticed through my checks, my **sett** really adds values and I can see it with **.allKeys()** function. But for some reason when the program is shut down, my INI file stay same. Do you have any ideas about this issue or advice, please? I can't understand why I've got this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't modify resources. You need to put .ini file in the file system if you want to write changes to it.

Comment: @hyde , so... I need then use QFile lib and change my file using this or something else? For now I can't find anything related to this.

Comment: Resources are embedded in the executable, and are read only. Writting to an embedded resource would require modifying the executable after compilation.

Comment: Hm, okay, thanks anyway. :т